# How can I show the code in formatted form to user in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I am receiving the code from the backend in plain text format. Like below...

```
def countNegatives(matrix): count = 0 for row in matrix: for num in row: if num < 0: count += 1 return count
```

It's in simple text form, but I want to display this to the user, and it should be **well formatted**. Like one below...

```
def countNegatives(matrix): 
    count = 0 
    for row in matrix: 
        for num in row: 
            if num < 0: 
                count += 1 
    return count
```

I want to format code of Javascript, Python, Java, C, C++, Ruby and CSS
Can someone provide me a way for doing this. Please help if possible...

Comment: To be clear - your example is Python but you don't mention Python. Do you need to format Python specifically within a React JS app?

Comment: I want to format code of Javascript, Python, Java, C, C++, Ruby and CSS in my React app. Thanks  @Rob Hogan.
I just missed to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html). There is probably some other code formatting libs out there. Using react, you wanna build yourself a custom hook for that.

Comment: can you share any example?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Raukaute, prettier is a good formatting lib. [Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/) of [prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html) is built by React + prettier webworker. You can find the source code on [Github](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/tree/main/website/playground), it is a good example. In a nutshell, the `index.js` create a WebWorker from static UMD js file (`prettier/standalone.js`) and call `format` API in `App`->`Playground`->`PrettierFormat` component.

Comment: Unfortunately, i find that prettier [python plugin](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-python) is deprecated while not completed.

Comment: Hi, please do not use answers for comments. Stackoverflow is a little bit different from other sites. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the js-beautify to do this.
It's not perfect but works stable

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify)